# C#: accessing Dictionary by using a partial class

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties, getter-setter, partial-classes

I'm trying to access a Dictionary in the following way, by using a partial class. The end purpose of this is to expose this dictionary and allow different methods to directly read/write from/to it.

**FilenameABC.cs** has this code, which seems to be OK for me so far:

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    partial class ClassA
    {
        public class ExampleDictionary
        {
            private Dictionary<int, string> _dict;

            public ExampleDictionary()
            {
                _dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FilenameDEF.cs** has this code and this is where I'm having difficulties. I'm not sure why the *.Add* methods don't work. In the first one I'm trying to use it just after creating an instance of the ExampleDictionary class, which seems to be quite counter intuitive (given my current level of knowledge, of course). In the second one, I'm trying to add elements from inside a method, which is

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    partial class ClassA
    {
        ExampleDictionary instanceOfDict = new ExampleDictionary();
        instanceOfDict.Add(1, "Test1"); // This does not work

        public static void FunctionA()
        {            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
            string text = $"Test{i}";
            instanceOfDict.Add(i, text); // This does not work as well              
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone assist, please?

Comment: You'd need to inherit `Dictionary` or expose the methods, but why are you doing this? It seems you don't even need the `ExampleDictionary` class at all.

Comment: First, there is no such thing as a _Partial Class_.  The `partial` keyword simply indicates that a class may be defined in more than one file.  The definition rules for the class remain the same, it's just that some of the class members may be defined in one file and other parts in other files.  But, the definition rules remain the same.  In particular, only class members may be defined at the _top level_, i.e., directly within the `class MyClass { /* stuff */ }` level.  Your code: `instanceOfDict.Add(1, "Test1");` is a function call, it can't exist at the top level of a class

Comment: I just noticed the second _does not work_.  That's a terrible description of a problem - you have a full error message, please share it with us.  Do you get a compiler error?  I'm guessing the first error describes something like I said in my first comment.  The second error is likely because a static method can't access an instance member.  Finally, an explanation of _what you are trying to do_ would be useful.

Comment: Hi @zaggler. The end purpose of this is to 'expose' the dictionary and allow different methods to directly read/write from/to it. Perhaps what I'm missing is this 'exposure' itself, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Hello @Flydog57. Thanks for helping. When it comes to the second 'error', there's no compilation error.  When writing the code, I just don't see '.Add' as a method. I see 'Equals', 'GetHashCode', 'GetType' and 'ToString'. Once this is declared as a Dictionary, I don't understand why I don't see Dictionary methods on it. I'm pretty sure the issue, as you said, is that 'a static method can't access an instance member', but I'm not sure how would I should do so instead. The end purpose of this is just to expose this dictionary and allow different methods to directly read/write from/to it.

Comment: @roccaforte - Then you could either expose the Dictionary itself by making it public, although then you allow basically anything, such as setting it to reference a totally different dictionary, which you may not want to allow. Alternatively, you can add methods to you `ExampleDictionary` class that in turn call the Dictionary's methods.

Answer (score 1):

The static method `FunctionA` cannot access instance members of `ClassA`.

Either change `FunctionA` to be non-static or make the dictionary field static.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't quite tell what you are trying to do.  But I'll do my best to show you some stuff.

I'm taking this sentence you wrote: *"The end purpose of this is to expose this dictionary and allow different methods to directly read/write from/to it."* as my guide

**Partial Class Issues**

As I mentioned in the comments: there is no such thing as a Partial Class. The partial keyword simply indicates that a class may be defined in more than one file. The definition rules for the class remain the same, it's just that some of the class members may be defined in one file and other parts in other files.

The issues you are having here have *nothing* to do with the `partial` keyword.

**Your Two *// This does not work* Notes**

The first one looks like this:

```
partial class ClassA
{
    ExampleDictionary instanceOfDict = new ExampleDictionary();
    instanceOfDict.Add(1, "Test1"); // This does not work
    //other code
}
```

The first line declares private member field of `ClassA` named `instanceOfDict` and initializes it.  That's why it compiles.

The second line tries to put runnable code (a function call) directly in the top-level scope of a class.  You can't do that.  You can put a bunch of things at the top level scope of a class (e.g., fields, properties, methods, delegates, enums, inner classes), but you can't put code there.

Your second issue looks like this:

```
public static void FunctionA()
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string text = $"Test{i}";
        instanceOfDict.Add(i, text); // This does not work as well              
    }          
}
```

FunctionA is a `static` method.  `instanceOfDict` is a private field of the class, not declared as static.  You can't refer to instance to instance-level members (methods, properties, fields, ...) from a static method.  Read up on the `static` keyword.

**Creating a Class that Selectively Exposes a Dictionary**

Since you want to do some dictionary work inside a class, but expose it to the outside, I went whole hog and made my class generic on `<TKey, TValue>` so that it works with Dictionaries of any type.

I also made it implement the [*Collection Initialization Pattern*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) so that you can initialize instances of your class just like it was a dictionary.

To use the Collection Initialization Pattern, your class must do to things:

1. Implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` (`T` can be any type, not just the type you are collecting - you can even just throw a `NotImplementedException` if you don't care)
2. Include a method that looks like `public void Add (SomeType atLeastOneParameter)`. You can have more than one overload of `Add` if you want.

So, I start with this (Note that it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public partial class TestExposedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _theDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        _theDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in _theDictionary)
        {
            yield return kvp.Value;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

That's enough to make a class mostly look like a dictionary (your probably want to add some way to get the data, etc.  But, that's up to you (you probably want to have an indexer (on `TKey`) and a `TryGetValue`.

But, let's add some more random functionality to the class (put this at the top level scope of the class):

```
    public int Count => _theDictionary.Count;

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetKeyValuePairs()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in _theDictionary)
        {
            yield return kvp;
        }
    }
```

That will allow you to see how many things are in your dictionary and allow you to iterate over the items (the `KeyValuePairs`) that the Dictionary collections.  Feel free to add more features.

Finally, to test this...

```
public static void Test()
{
    var testDict = new TestExposedDictionary<int, string> {
        {1, "one" },
        {5, "five" },
        {8, "eight" },
        {10, "ten" },
        {105, "hundredFive" },
    };

    // I can call Add in the normal way as well:
    testDict.Add(300, "threeHundred");

    Console.WriteLine($"TestDict Count: {testDict.Count}");
    foreach (string s in testDict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
TestDict Count: 6
one
five
eight
ten
hundredFive
threeHundred
```

**Splitting this using Partial**

I don't know why you want to use `partial class`.  Normally this is done to have two chunks of code that are edited/maintained by different personas (the typical reason is for Visual Studio's templating/wizarding mechanism to maintain one side of the `partial class` and the programmer the other.

The rules are pretty simple, you simply declare `public partial class MyClass` in two files.  The two files must be in the same project (i.e., compiled into the same *Assembly*) and the classes must be in the same namespace.  Once you do that, just split the (top-level scope) bits and pieces across the two `partial class` declarations.

In this cases I'd probably split it this way:

- One one side, I'd put the two functions needed to implement the declared `IEnumerator<TValue>`:

  - `public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()`
  - `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`
- One the other side, I'd put everything else:

  - The dictionary declaration and intialization
  - The other enumerator: `public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetKeyValuePairs()`
  - `public int Count => _theDictionary.Count;`
  - `public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)`

Comment: I cannot express how grateful I am for this. This also helped me to break a few misconceptions I had. Sometimes learn programming gets a but frustrating, but luckly there are amazing individuals like you, that dedicate a piece of your day to help others. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I do. Fortunately, I have just achieved this badge that allows me as a newcomer to start trading such currency.  :-)